# How to copy multiple files dynamically in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

The main motto of the pipeline is to copy the data from Source to Sink. But the number of Sources and its respective Sink will not be constant, meaning it may increase or decrease every day. How to build this pipeline?

I got to know using something called as "mapping tables" this can be achieved.

I am unable to find any such thing in Azure data factory.
What is this 'mapping table' is this a concept or some option within Copy activity or what?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the source and sink tables list known and **the column names in each source and sink are same**, then using single copy activity inside a for-loop will do the job. As the column names are same, copy activity will dynamically map the schemas of each source and sink if we left the projection empty.

But if the column names are different, then **we need to build the mapping for each iteration**. For this, the **mapping table** will be used. ****Mapping table** means, a table which has the information about the `source file name` and `target file name`, `source file column names` and `target file column names`**.

In every pipeline run, we need to truncate this table and insert the source and target tables information into it like below sample.

| source_name | target_name | source_columns | target_columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file1 | target1 | Id,Name,Age,Marks | id,Firstname,Years_old,marks |
| file2 | target2 | subject_name,no_passed,no_failed | name,pass,fail |

After inserting, get this table as an array of objects and iterate through that using for-loop.

Use the dataset parameters for the copy activity source and dataset filenames and pass the `@item().source_name` and `@item().target_name` inside the for-loop.

Then, to build the mapping JSON, use a stored procedure by passing the current source and target names and call that using lookup activity or stored procedure activity.

Go through this [blog](https://blogs.perficient.com/2022/07/21/column-mappings-as-a-dynamic-content-in-azure-data-factory/) by **@Shubham Nandanwar** to know how to create the stored procedure.

Pass the output mapping JSON from the activity output to copy activity dynamic content expression.

In this process, in each iteration the stored procedure will give the mapping JSON and the copy activity will copy the file dynamically using that JSON.